# How to show a form field if none exists in a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails form which has menu_items and these menu_items have a price and a price comment (:has_one). However, our data currently doesn't have price info. How would I adjust the below to code to build this so that this exists?

```
<%= form.fields_for :menu_items do |mi| %>
  <div id='menu-item-<%=mi.object.id %>'>
  <%= mi.text_field :header, :size => 75 %>
      <%=mi.fields_for :price do |p| %>
        price: <%=p.text_field :price %>
        price comment:<%=p.text_field :price_comment %>
     <% end %> 
  </div>
```

<% end %>

thx

Comment: Are you asking how to add the data stored in the form to the database?  Have you created a migration which adds the price and price_comment column fields to the database?

Comment: y - price is a separate table. That's the issue. It has a has_one relationship and currently doesn't validate for the existence of a price. There would be scenarios where there wouldn't be a price. The issue is that if you don't have a price, it doesn't render the form fields and I'm trying to figure out how to get them to show. thx